# Axios response never resolves

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get some data using Axios and then filter it. It worked strangely and at first it showed an array with data in it but 0 length. Then I created the if(data) before the dataFilter() and it was showing the data as null but when I saved the code after a while it worked perfectly, it showed the data and the length was correct. I then created the if(response && response.ok) statement and it shows absolutely nothing. I think it is never resolving the promise and that is the cause why it is showing nothing.

```jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ChildComponent from "./Boxes.jsx";

function Data() {
  const path = "https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies/";
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [complexBodies, setComplexBodies] = useState([]);
  const [simpleBodies, setSimpleBodies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await axios
        .get(path)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response && response.ok) {
            setData(response.data.bodies);
            setIsLoading(false);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    };
    fetchData();
    if (data) dataFilter();
  }, [path]);

  const dataFilter = () => {
    try {
      console.log(data);
      const filterComplex = (body) => body.moons != null;
      const complexBodies = data.filter(filterComplex);
      setComplexBodies((props) => [...props, ...complexBodies]);
      console.log(complexBodies.length);
      const filterSimple = (body) => body.moons == null;
      const simpleBodies = data.filter(filterSimple);
      console.log(simpleBodies.length);
      setSimpleBodies((props) => [...props, ...simpleBodies]);
      console.log(simpleBodies);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error al filtrar");
    }
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return <></>;
  }
  console.log(complexBodies);
  return (
    <div className="Data">
      <ChildComponent
        simpleBodies={simpleBodies}
        complexBodies={complexBodies}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Data;
```

Comment: Create a new effect hook with `data` as a dependency to run your `dataFilter()` function

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much, I've trying to solve this the whole week.

Comment: Just a hint... don't mix `async` / `await` with `.then()`, `.catch()` etc. It just makes code confusing. Also, Axios doesn't have a `response.ok` property. See https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema